# How to change UnitPath property in systemd?

Tags: systemd, xdg

I'm experimenting with a non-standard home directory setup making heavy use of `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME`, `$XDG_CACHE_HOME`, etc. and most programs have run just fine. Unfortunately, my systemd user service for [`mopidy`](https://github.com/mopidy/mopidy) is not working with this configuration.

I have `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` set to `~/cfg` and, according to `man systemd.unit`,

```
$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/systemd/user or        │ User configuration
$HOME/.config/systemd/user              │ ($XDG_CONFIG_HOME is
                                        │ used if set, ~/.config
                                        │ otherwise)
```

`systemctl --user start mopidy` should work correctly finding the `mopidy.service` file there (at `~/cfg/systemd/user/mopidy.service`) which is is not happening.

I have of course tried moving it to some of the other directories listed in the man page and, though `systemctl` did recognize it in a few of them, it still wasn't reading the configuration (for `mopidy` itself) from the right location.

Interestingly, `systemctl --user show --property=UnitPath` only returns some options from `.config` instead of what my `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` is actually set to:

```
UnitPath=/home/uver/.config/systemd/user.control /run/user/1000/systemd/user.control /run/user/1000/systemd/transient /run/user/1000/systemd/generator.early /home/uver/.config/systemd/user /etc/xdg/systemd/user /etc/systemd/user /run/user/1000/systemd/user /run/systemd/user /run/user/1000/systemd/generator /home/uver/.local/share/systemd/user /usr/local/share/systemd/user /usr/share/systemd/user /usr/local/lib/systemd/user /usr/lib/systemd/user /run/user/1000/systemd/generator.late
```

My question is: how could I manually change the paths in this value or how could I force systemd to look in my custom directory for user units/services?

Thanks :)

Comment: You don't say where/when you are setting `XDG_CONFIG_HOME`. You could try
`systemctl --user set-environment XDG_CONFIG_HOME=/some/path` or create file `~/.pam_environment` to hold `XDG_CONFIG_HOME   DEFAULT=@{HOME}/myconfig` (man pam_env pam_env.conf).

Comment: I've been setting a couple of those important ones it in `/etc/profile` (with less crucial ones in my elvish `rc.elv`). I guess `/etc/profile` must come after systemd has generated that variable or something. I tried `~/.pam_environment` but then my X sessions started breaking until I deleted it from another TTY. I'll look into it again sometime but I'm just too busy (read: lazy) to worry about it right now. Thanks for your suggestion though.